Задача на комбинаторику(ПСП)
Ограничение по времени работы: 1 секунда
Посчитайте количество правильных скобочных последовательностей длины 2n (n открывающих скобок и n закрывающих), составленных из круглых и квадратных скобок так, что внутри любой пары круглых скобок нет квадратных скобок.
Например при n = 5, ответ 625.
Входные данные
В единственной строке через пробел записано целое неотрицательное число n, не превосходящее 1000.
Выходные данные
Выведите остаток от деления количества искомых правильных скобочных последовательностей на 10^9 + 7.
Ниже приведён мой код.
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
long long MOD = 1e9 + 7;
long long binomialCoefficient(int n, int k) {
    if (k < 0 || k > n) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (k > n - k) {
        k = n - k;
    }
    long long res = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        res = (res * (n - i)) / (i + 1);
    }
    return res;
}
long long a(int n) {
    long long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        sum += (((binomialCoefficient(2 * i + 1, i) * binomialCoefficient(2 * n - 1, n - i - 1)) / (2 * n - 1)) % MOD);
        sum %= MOD;
    }
    return sum;
}
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    long long result = a(n + 1);
    cout << result % MOD;
}

Мне кажется он правильный, но у моего кода бывает переполнение, видимо я где-то не беру по модулю(1e9 + 7).
Скажите пожалуйста, что исправить!

Для начала при умножении делайте не a*b%c, а (a%с)*(b%c)%с

Если вы про эту строчку sum += (((binomialCoefficient(2 * i + 1, i) * binomialCoefficient(2 * n - 1, n - i - 1)) / (2 * n - 1)) % MOD); , то я не могу, т.к. ответ при больших числах будет другой

Ну, раз вам виднее, как решать, то кто я такой, чтоб давать вам советы?... Кстати, можно сначала поделить, а потом множить...

Извините, если ответил грубо, но у меня почему-то не выходит сначала взять модуль, а потом поделить, просто если сделать так sum += ((((binomialCoefficient(2 * i + 1, i) % MOD) * (binomialCoefficient(2 * n - 1, n - i - 1) % MOD)) / (2 * n - 1)) % MOD);, то ответ совсем другой получается. подправьте, если не прав

"Кстати, можно сначала поделить, а потом множить..."

Дада, так тоже исправил, всё равно что-то не то sum += (((binomialCoefficient(2 * i + 1, i) % MOD) * ((binomialCoefficient(2 * n - 1, n - i - 1) / n21) % MOD)) % MOD); Может я что-то не то написал?

n21 = (2 * n - 1)

Возможно переполнение внутри binomialCoefficient.

Дайте URL, посмотреть...

Harry, Вы про что?

Вы же где-то на каком-то сайте эту задачу делаете? Вот и дайте посмотреть живьем, а не в вашей интерпретации :) Что такое URL, знаете? Простыми словами - адрес...

Спасибо за помощь, задачу я уже решил(другим способом)
